# Member Berries in South Park

Tags: south-park

In the latest season of [South Park](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0121955/), people are eating member berries, which are grape-like fruit that talks and says nostalgic stuff, like "'member Star Wars?" or "'member Woodstock?".

Are those a reference to something? Or just random south park non-sense?

Comment: As I recall, only men seem to eat them?  If that's the case, then at least one reference would be the "[male member](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/male_member)", especially since the boys exposing their members is a theme of this season.  But I wouldn't necessarily think this could be the only reference.

Comment: I thought it was a euphemism for getting high and living in the past.

Comment: The season is still ongoing -- currently we're only halfway -- and an explanation might still be forthcoming.

Comment: The Bruce Springsteen song Glory Days comes to mind.

Comment: Does anyone else find this season really not funny? I miss the old stupid and funny seasons.. maybe I am under the influence of member berries too...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't find any official sources from Parker and Stone about this, but from what I understood, Member Berries refer to a current trend of people saying that life was better in the past ([90s kids memes](https://www.google.fr/#q=90s+kids+memes)). Instead of focusing on real current problems and actually resolve them, people just sit and remember old stuff.

They refer to :

- Todays Hollywood reboot movies or extending old franchises ("Member Ghostbusters? Member Star Wars?")
- Racist ideas ("Member when there were not so many Mexicans.?"). It may look like Trump references to "make America great again".
- Viewers that say older episodes of South Park were better. However they *member* us an old episode when they bring back the "[Giant Douche and Turd Sandwitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douche_and_Turd)" joke from 2004.